# replace multiple substrings at given index

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I want to replace human names in the string with html characters

```
Barack Obama and Abraham Lincon were US presidents
0    4 7  11     17   23 25  30           <- index
```

```
replacementArr = [
  {start: 0,  end: 11, class: "alive"},
  {start: 17, end: 30, class: "dead"},
]
```

**expected output:**

```
<span class="alive">Barack Obama<span> and <span class="dead">Abraham Lincon<span> were US presidents
```

**The problem:**

The problem I am facing is that if I replace *Barack Obama* with html string, start and end index for *Abraham Lincon* become invalid. This is because there are additional letters in the string.

One possible solution is replacing in reverse but this doesnt work if a replacement is nested.

**Nested example:**

```
<span class="alive">
    <span class="firstName">Barack</span>
    <span class="lastName">Obama</span>
<span>
    and 
<span class="dead">
    <span class="firstName">Abraham</span> 
    <span class="lastName">Lincon</span>
<span>
were US presidents


replacementArr = [
    {start: 0,  end: 11, class: "alive"},
    {start: 0,  end: 4, class: "firstName"},
    {start: 17,  end: 23, class: "firstName"},
    {start: 7,  end: 11, class: "lastName"},
    {start: 25,  end: 30, class: "lastName"},
    {start: 17, end: 30, class: "dead"},
  ]
```

Pls advice.

Comment: How would the `replacementArr` look for the nested example ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Just added to my question

Comment: Where's the actual JavaScript that you wrote? We're supposed to fix broken code not write new code.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a variant of the replacements, where each new entry is about inserting one tag (either opening or closing -- as separate entries). Then sort those, and build a new string.

When indexes are equal for two entries, the sort order should put closing tags before opening tags, and if they are of the same type (opening/closing), then order by the content size they have behind them (negative size when opening, positive size when closing).

```js
let replacementArr = [{start: 0,  end: 11, class: "alive"},{start: 0,  end: 5, class: "firstName"},{start: 17,  end: 23, class: "firstName"},{start: 7,  end: 11, class: "lastName"},{start: 25,  end: 30, class: "lastName"},{start: 17, end: 30, class: "dead"}];
let phrase = "Barack Obama and Abraham Lincon were US presidents"

let result = replacementArr.flatMap(o => [
    { idx: o.start, tag: `<${o.class}>`, order: o.start-o.end-1 },
    { idx: o.end+1, tag: `</${o.class}>`, order: o.end+1-o.start }
]).sort((a, b) => 
    a.idx - b.idx || a.order - b.order
).concat({tag: ""}).reduce((acc, {idx, tag}) => ({
    str: acc.str + phrase.slice(acc.idx, idx) + tag,
    idx
}), { str: "", idx: 0 }).str;    

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Retain the original string and extract elements out of it.

```js
const inputString = "Barack Obama and Abraham Lincon were US presidents"

const replacementArr = [
  {start: 0,  end: 11, class: "alive"},
  {start: 17, end: 31, class: "dead"}
]

const output = replacementArr.map(element => { 
const extract = inputString.substring(element.start, element.end)
return "<span class=\"" + element.class + "\">" + extract + "<span>"
})

let currMax = 0;
replacementArr.forEach(element => element.end > currMax? currMax = element.end: currMax)

console.log(output.join(" and ") + " " + inputString.substring(currMax, inputString.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

By sorting the `replacementArr` based on length instead of replacing in reverse

```js
var string = "Barack Obama and Abraham Lincon were US presidents"

var replacementArr =  [
  {start: 0,  end: 11, class: "alive"},
  {start: 0,  end: 4, class: "firstName"},
  {start: 17,  end: 23, class: "firstName"},
  {start: 7,  end: 11, class: "lastName"},
  {start: 25,  end: 30, class: "lastName"},
  {start: 17, end: 30, class: "dead"},
]

replacementArr.sort((a, b) => (b.end - b.start) - (a.end - a.start))

var replacementStr = replacementArr.map(i => ({
  str: string.substring(i.start, i.end + 1),
  class: i.class
}))

replacementStr.forEach(i => {
  string = string.replace(i.str, '<span class="' + i.class + '">' + i.str + '</span>')
})

document.write(string)
console.log(string)
```

Comment: This solution wont work if some name are repeated.
`var string = "test test"

var replacementArr =  [
  {start: 6,  end: 10, class: "test"},
]`